# Run a transaction within SP then return a table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, transaction

I need a SP (or anything like this) which must be able to do some changes on specific tables then return content of one of them.

Something like this pseudo-code:

```
create procedure
    begin
        begin transaction
            update myTable set transferDate = GETDATE() where condition;
            insert into transferLog values(@userId, GETDATE());
        commit transaction

        return myTable data
    end
```

Comment: Replace `return` with `SELECT * FROM` and you are done.

Comment: I'm working with C#. Can I retrieve table in application?

Comment: Yes, just invoke the procedure with sqlcommand.ExecuteReader

Comment: Yes, it works. I'm using EF, so the code will be : `dbCtx.storedProcName().ToList()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add OUTPUT before condition, with "inserted" prefix and add column names

```
create procedure
begin
    begin transaction
        update myTable set transferDate = GETDATE()
        OUTPUT inserted.transferDate ,inserted.OtherExistingValue...
        where condition;
        insert into transferLog 
        OUTPUT inserted.column1, inserted.column2
        values(@userId, GETDATE());
    commit transaction

end
```

This way you will get two result sets, one for inserted and another for update
if you want to marge them

if you want to get a single result set of both actions you would need to add @TableVariable and insert output of both actions and then return the table as:

```
create procedure
begin
    begin transaction
        DECLARE @table table(TransferDateUpdated datetime2,UserID int)
        update myTable set transferDate = GETDATE()
        OUTPUT inserted.transferDate INTO @table(TrasnferedDateUpdated)
        where condition;
        insert into transferLog 
        OUTPUT inserted.column1 INTO @table (UserID )
        values(@userId, GETDATE());

    SELECT TransferDateUpdated,UserID from @table
    commit transaction

end
```

This way you will get record for each action separately within a same result set